# How to get a horizontal perspective - CSS

Tags: css

I am trying a curtain blinds thing - http://jsfiddle.net/ykcgkvu2/
Though it works ok, wanted to improve it by applying a horizontal user perspective.

Current Scene: There is a gray wall which has a curtain with red / blue blinds. When they rotate, you also get to see the wall, which is not so appealing, as I think there should be only 2 colors visible and not 3.

Expected Scene: Imagine you are standing at the extreme left or right of the wall. When you see the blinds rotation, only the red or blue colors are visible and not the gray wall.

So, is it possible to achieve this. I tried using `perspective-origin`, but no luck.

**HTML:**

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <figure class="front">1f</figure>
        <figure class="back">1b</figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
     width: 10%;
     height: 100vh;
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     overflow: hidden;     
     perspective: 800px;
 }
```

[image]

Update : Please check the picture. The user is standing at an angle to the curtain. The pic shows blinds in transition. During start, middle or finish, from this angle, user doesnt see the wall behind. Only the front/back colors of the blind.

If you are still unable to visualize what I have in mind, just place yourself in a tangent angle where you do not get to see the wall at all but just the front/back of the blinds during start, middle, finish of the transition...

Hope I am making some sense.

Thank you everyone for the thoughts. I just wanted to see if this was possible.

Comment: Why not avoid the `background-color` on `body` altogether?

Comment: The problem remains the some. Then gray, now white....

Comment: I think I figured out what you want, but anyway can you paint a few roughly pictures of result you want to achieve? Maybe start of transition, middle and near finish.

Comment: uhhh paint??? I will try. But meanwhile just imagine this. Current is You standing right in front of the curtain. Expected is you are standing at the left/right end of the wall and looking at the blinds transition.

Comment: @Qwerty: But you can never get rid of that white background with pure CSS. It will always remain. I would be surprised if you can get rid of it in any other means too.

Comment: I think you have a misconception of what one would see when standing at the extreme left or right. Because during rotation, every blind will eventually point in the exact direction of the viewer. From that angle, another blind is "behind" that blind - for "real-world" blinds, which are non-zero-depth, this is perceived as a a colour, but computed blinds will vanish due to zero-depth. I mean, [look](https://jsfiddle.net/ykcgkvu2/5/).

Comment: @StepanTsymbal. Sorry dont know how to do that in paint but added a pic and updated the Question. Please check.

Comment: I've just made a perspective working some way with your blinds: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykcgkvu2/6/). Maybe you can experiment with that and it'll help

Comment: @Qwerty Hm... But if you always seeing one side on blinds (so you never seeing something behind), How the color will swap then?

Comment: @Qwerty: The key question is this - at one point during the rotation the blinds would be perpendicular to the eye and at point it can neither show the front side nor the back side. What do you expect to be shown then?

Comment: @StepanTsymbal. What you said is right for real life blinds that only rotate 90deg and back. but in my case 180deg.

Comment: @Harry. The key Question arises when user is exactly in front of the curtain. But what I wish for is make it look like the user is looking from an angle. That way always only red/blue is visible. The red to blue transition looks more appealing. But anyways...just a crazy idea

Comment: @Qwerty If you will stand at extreme left or right positions all the blinds width will be one exact blind width? Oh, gimme few minutes. I'll try to draw it

Comment: @Qwerty In order to get from 0° to 180°, you have to pass 90° though - or 270°, which has the same effect. If you only look at the width of the blinds, you now have a transition from 100% to 100% via 0% (using a sine function). Now, you *could* exchange that 0% for infinite, then you'd have a tangent function... this way your blinds could cover the entire area at all times, but that's gonna look very weird.

Comment: @Qwerty: Sorry but I am totally unable to visualize whatever you are trying to achieve. However differently I position myself and look at the blinds, I still see them perpendicular to the eye. Either the wall (or) the blind that is behind (in case of each blind having a delayed start) will show up.

Comment: @Harry. Dont be. It's just that I am unable to explain it the right way. This is something we see everyday. Maybe it's not possible with css.

Comment: @Qwerty http://imgur.com/9SdzTmP — in any case you will see what is behind blinds. If you will stand at nearest to extreme position — blinds will be only straight line in perpendicular position.

Comment: @StepanTsymbal. Appreciate your effort. You are right I guess.